How to connect to TeraData in Mule application using trustStore in TLS based on Generic connection?
I'm trying to connect to teraData using Mule application. i'm able to establish connectivity using Generic connection where i pass the db creds via URL. However,
i wanted to establish connectivity with Teradata using truststore in TLS configuration through db url.
When i pass these parameters in the url SSLMODE=require,SSLTRUSTSTORE=clientTrustStore.jks,SSLTRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=****.
I'm getting error invalid parameter "SSLTRUSTSTORE" or "SSLTRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD"
i read many articles on teradata. Howewer, i have not come across any similar approach in teradata where i can pass ssltruststore,sslpassword via db url.
any help will be appreciated.

Connect how? What type of connection are you trying to establish? What have you tried?

@aled I have updated the post

What version of Teradata JDBC driver? SSLTRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD requires 20.00.00.14 or later.

@james11 that's still not enough detail. You should provide a [mre]. I'm guessing you are using Mule Database connector. Add the complete Mule configuration of the connector as XML, including the full URL (masking confidential data), exact versions of the connector, mule, JDBC driver and JDK, complete error messages with details, where in the source project are the JKS files and any other relevant details. Use [code block] format for text information like code, configurations and logs, for readability.
